# How to make something like a ImageSlider in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

First I will explain what I want to do:

I can take photos from camera or gallery and take it to a `ImageView`.
Now I want to add the function to add more than just one `ImageView`.

I've seen many times in others Apps this icon:

[image]

For me, it means that I can add a Picture. This is displayed just one time. If I take/add a picture in that, I want to display another Icon besides.

Or is there a better solution for this?
I want to let the User decide, how many pictures he can add.

I hope it's clear what I want to build and someone can give me the right way how to do it.

I didn't know what title would hit my problem. If someone knows a better, please edit!

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your point. You need something like below image:

[image]

I suggest to use recyclerview. Set your recyclerview layout as gridlayout then set an imageview as add button. By pressing the image, load picture from device and add another imageview to your recyclerview and again set it as add button.

Comment: You're welcome. You can even use [recent-images](https://github.com/amirarcane/recent-images) library to make your app more attractive

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe think about using Picasso?

http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android